# SGP30 circuit not working

Tags: sensor, schematics, esp32

I am building a PCB to show environmental data on a led matrix. Everything works perfectly except this SGP30 sensor I am using. It gets detected, but only sends default values at all times. I have followed [Adafruit schematics](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/050/060/original/adafruit_products_schem.png?1515783618) as reference.

The code itself should be correct because it works perfectly with a nodemcu connected with an off-the-shelf SGP30 dev board.

I have spent days trying to figure out the issue but cannot afford to get new boards made without knowing and fixing the error. It will be super helpful if you could have a look and see and see what might be the problem...

Link to the project easyeda page [here](https://oshwlab.com/dhruvkumars/livegrid_copy).

Happy to add part links if that helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope to capture the waveform on SCL/SDA and check if really the data sent by SGP30 matches what you read via the MCU? The schematics look good as far as I can see

Comment: I don't have one but I can get it. Good advice I will come back with updates.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the issue was in the software. To be precise it was about calibration of  the sensors. Every sgp30 has a different baseline which needs to be calibrated and stored and takes 12 hours.
I was using baseline values of one of the two sensors for both - which was disrupting and not letting the sensor do its thing.
Finally, these sensors are really not that good and have a lot of issues. Same issue and answer is documented here-
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SGP30/issues/25